# EF Core child entities automatically added to parent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a question about some (for me) strange behaviour in EF Core:

Take for example the following code:

```
efOrder = _context.Orders.ActiveOnly().FirstOrDefault(ord => ord.Id == id); //ActiveOnly() filters out my soft deleted orders
//No orderlines here
_context.Set<OrderLine>().RemoveRange(_context.OrderLine.ActiveOnly().Where(ol => ol.OrderId == efOrder.Id));
//sudden orderlines on efOrder here
```

Why does my `efOrder` now suddenly have the `OrderLines` when I did not add them to `efOrder`? 
Because this occasionaly results in a severed association error, how do I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Comment: Are you using same instance `_context` somewhere else where you read `OrderLines`

Comment: @DavidG Thank you! adding .AsNoTracking() after _context.OrderLine  lookup query worked!

Comment: In case you didn't read the "news", it's called EF Core and has the versions 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0. **not** 7. Since two years ago, so actually not "news" at all

Comment: @Tseng I don't see how this adds to the question?

Comment: Simple, there is no EF7. There is no EF Core 7 (well maybe in 5-6 years). The documentation states nothing about "EF7". So your question implies you did not even take a look in the documentation or at the nuget package. Second, its confusing for people who search for help, when they search for EF Core 2.0 and find question/answer for EF7. Even more confusing when sometime in Future EF Core 7.0 comes, to have some utterly outdated question completely unrelated to the product the person was searching for.

Comment: And terms such as EF7 imply, that it's the next version of EF6. **IT'S NOT**, EF Core is a **complete rewrite** and still lacks many of the features that used to be in EF6. The product was deliberately named "EF Core 1.0" half a year before it was released to avoid such confusions and you just keep it up, but still using this outdated term **two years later**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to run the query without tracking the lookup query;

```
efOrder = _context.Orders.ActiveOnly().FirstOrDefault(ord => ord.Id == id); 
//ActiveOnly() filters out my soft deleted orders
//No orderlines here
_context.Set<OrderLine>().RemoveRange(_context.OrderLine.AsNoTracking().ActiveOnly().Where(ol => ol.OrderId == efOrder.Id));
//Orderlines are not added
```

Thanks for the help.